# How do i use user input for a string array that is in a while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to convert the user input from the question of students name and score into a array.
I also need help to printout the array.
The while loop is using boolean loopNaming as its condition, and i is updated everytime the loop occurs.

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double score;

        boolean loopNaming=true;
        int i=0;
        String[] name = new String[i];



         while(loopNaming==true)
            {
                System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");
                name[i] = keyboard.next();

                if(name[i].equals("done"))
                {
                    loopNaming = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter score: ");
                    score = keyboard.nextDouble();
                }
                i=i+1;

            }
            System.out.println(name[i]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `while(loopNaming==true)`  had better change to `while(loopNaming)`

Comment: `int i=0;
        String[] name = new String[i];` - looks like trouble ahead

Comment: What actually goes wrong? Are you getting index out of bounds exceptions when accessing `name[i]`?

Comment: name array is size zero,. It will give array out of bound exception. Use an aaraylist.

Comment: `String[] name = new String[i];` the array size will be 0,so an `indexOutofboundexception` will happen,you can use `List` instead of `array`

Comment: Move  i=i+1; to inside else segment, otherwise final sysout will give an exception.

Comment: how can i change it to a list?

Comment: @Buh: You can use my answer. You don't have to use array at all instead ArrayList will do your job and you need to declare a List for storing all scores too as you can't store scores of all students in just one score variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify the logic of your program and write something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Double> scoreList = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while (true) {
        System.out.printf("Enter first name of student or done to finish: ");
        String fname = keyboard.next();
        if (fname.equals("done")) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.printf("Enter last name of student: ");
        String lname = keyboard.next();
        nameList.add(fname + " " + lname);
        System.out.println("Enter score: ");
        scoreList.add(keyboard.nextDouble());
    }
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("Names: " + nameList);
    System.out.println("scores: " + scoreList);
}
```

Comment: is it possible to change the code to let a name containing both first and last, space included to the name array.

Comment: Yes of course, let me edit my answer to include that

Comment: Updated code and now you can enter firstname and lastname as prompted by the program. Please check and let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the array to an arraylist and moved  i=i+1; to inside else segment. Also changed the final print statement to print the list.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
  {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      double score;

      boolean loopNaming=true;
      int i=0;
      ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();



       while(loopNaming==true)
          {
              System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");
              name.add(keyboard.next());

              if(name.get(i).equals("done"))
              {
                  loopNaming = false;
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println("Enter score: ");
                  score = keyboard.nextDouble();
                  i=i+1;
              }

          }
          System.out.println(name);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly recommend using a List data structure:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double score;
    boolean loopNaming = true;
    List<String> name = new ArrayList<>();

    while (loopNaming) {
        System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");
        String input = keyboard.next();

        if (input.equals("done")) {
            loopNaming = false;
        } else {
            name.add(input);
            System.out.println("Enter score: ");
            score = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(name.toString());
}
```

However, if you very much would like to use an array, you could make your own method to increase the size of your array each time a new name is added:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    double score;
    int i = 0;
    boolean loopNaming = true;
    String[] name = {};

    while (loopNaming) {
        System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");
        String input = keyboard.next();

        if (input.equals("done")) {
            loopNaming = false;
        } else {
            name = increaseArray(name);
            name[i] = input;
            System.out.println("Enter score: ");
            score = keyboard.nextDouble();
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
}

public static String[] increaseArray(String[] arr) {
    String[] temp = new String[arr.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I was unsure what your plan was with your score variable, but this would be two ways to achieve your desired result.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double score;

        boolean loopNaming=true;
        int i=0;
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();



        while(loopNaming==true)
        {
            System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");

            String input = keyboard.next();
            if(input.equals("done"))
            {
                loopNaming = false;
            }
            else
            {   name.add(input);
                System.out.println("Enter score: ");
                score = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            i=i+1; //no need to use

        }
        System.out.println(name);

    }
```

You should use a `dynamic list` because You can't resize an array in Java. The second point **when the user gives "done", you should not put it in the list** so check it before the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your String array with size 0. that's why you cant add elements in to it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameArray {
 public static void main(String [] args){
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     double score[] = new double[10];

     boolean loopNaming=true;
     int i=0;
     String namae;
     String[] name = new String[10];
     int count = 0;


     while(loopNaming==true){
         System.out.printf("Enter name of student or done to finish: ");
         name[i] = keyboard.next();

         if(name[i].equals("done")){
             loopNaming = false;
         }
         else{
            System.out.println("Enter score: ");
            score[i] = keyboard.nextDouble();
            count++;
         }
         i=i+1;

     }
     for(int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
         System.out.println(name[j]+" "+score[j]);
     }
 }
}
```

Try this code or you can go for any other data structures.